# WPF recursive treeview with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm new to WPF and MVVM pattern. I'm trying to bind recursively a Treeview to ObservableCollections. 
I have searched so many times on this site, but I found no answers to my problem.
Here it is my Model class:

```
public class CategoryCounter
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Parent { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter> Children => new ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter>(/*some linq code here*/);
```

And the ViewModel class:

```
public class CategoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private string supplier;

    private ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter> categories;
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter> Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set
        {
            if (value != categories)
            {
                categories = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetSupplier(string supplier)
    {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter>(CategoryContatori.GetRootBySupplier(supplier));
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now, when i call "SetSupplier()" the collection is filled and it is all ok, but the view does not show me anything.
This is the XAML code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dbModel:CategoryCounter}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

How can I bind the children items even if they are the same object? Is this the problem?
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You do not raise a `PropertyChanged` event when you assign to `Categories`

Comment: So just move the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` call from the SetSupplier method into the Categories property setter. That said, `x:Type dbModel:CategoryContatori` looks odd. DataType should be `CategoryCounter`, or not be set at all.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to translate that.. the code is ok.
Just moved the NotifyPropertyChanged() but the UI is showing nothing

Comment: `CategoryCounter.Children` probably shouldn't be an expression-bodied property, as that will generate a new `ObservableCollection` each time it's accessed

Comment: @canton7 so what am i supposed to do?

Comment: @Luca make it a normal property (`{ get; }` or `{ get; set; }` etc)

Comment: Try using Snoop to see what the various bindings, properties and DataContext of your TreeView are set to. See: https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the template directly

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Resources generally need to be in the parent of the item that needs to access them.

EDIT: Although having just done a quick search this may not be the case for TreeViews, so it's likely that INPC is your problem as already noted in the comments.

Comment: I used all the hints you all gave to me but still a white UI.. I don't know how to handle it anymore, I tried everything by now

Answer (score 0):

Raise the `PropertyChanged` in the setter of your `Categories` property:

```
private ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter> categories;
public ObservableCollection<CategoryCounter> Categories
{
    get { return categories; }
    set
    {
        categories = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Categories));
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the `Categories` property and the `Children` property return materialized collections of `CategoryCounter` objects.

Comment: Sorry, how can I determine if the properties return materialized collections? If I debug the code, I can see that in the Categories property there are a collection of items, but the view does not show them.

Comment: Do your bindings work? Are you seeing any binding errors in the output window when you debug? What's the `DataContext` of the `TreeView`?

Comment: No output errors, so I think bindings are working. The datacontext of the usercontrol that contains the treeview is CategoriesViewModel, set in the xaml.cs of the view. Usercontrol contains only this treeview. @mm8

Comment: @LucaSantolini: Why do you "think" the bindings are working when you don't see any data?

Comment: I used Snoop and the bindings are working (the itemsource of the treeview tells Path=Categories) and the collection contains objects.

Comment: If the binding to `Categories`works, you'll see the `Name` of each category in the `TreeView`.